# Android Sliding Menu Hangs UI

Tags: android, performance, slidingmenu

Sliding Menu in my app blocks UI after opening it, `SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW` only in Android Lollipop this issues happens.

```
menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_MARGIN);
menu.setBehindOffset(130);
menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
menu.attachToActivity(_activity, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_WINDOW,false);
menu.setMenu(R.layout.left_menue_new);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no this ansewer is not fruitfull, I myself solve the answer by just adding a single line in the menifest i.e.

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me i tested on api level 21 and 22 and 19 also

> if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT ==21)return;

add this line at  after line Num 974 in SlidingMenu.java[image]

Vote up if it works may be helpfull for others